# getting the value of an attribute using javascript every time a user clicks on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I have a navigation menu but I am intending to get the "title" that belongs to each link that the user clicks each time in javascript. I tried the function below using jquery but I do not see it where it seem to fail. Any help is extremely appreciated.

```js
     jquery(function() {
        var title = jquery(title).attr('title');    
        console.log("you have selected" + "" title);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title = "google 1" href="https://www.google.com">Visit google</a>
    <a title = "Yahoo" href="https://www.yahoo.com">Visit This link</a>
    <a title = "Verizon Wireless" href="https://www.Verizon.com">Visit Verizon</a>
    <a title = "Social Media" href="https://www.facebook.com">Visit facebook/a>
```

**Result :**

```
  you have selected Social Media
```

Comment: The code is running when the page loads, not when the user clicks on something.

Comment: it needs to be in a click handler, that seems obvious.

Comment: I don't see how the code is working at all, where do you set the variable `title`?

Comment: Do you want to use either Javascript only or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have two typos in your code:

```
console.log("you have selected" + "" title);
```

is missing a `+` between `""` and `title` and that's what causes the error when you run the code.

Second, you are missing `<` before the closing `a` of the last hyperlink.

Even after fixing those things, the main issue is that your function is set to run as soon as the HTML is loaded. You need to set up an event handler for the clicking of the links.

You also aren't selecting the `title` attribute of the `a` elements correctly.

Keep in mind though that clicking on a link navigates the user away from the current page, so trying to get messages sent to the console, will only show them for a moment before those messages disappear and the new page is loaded. Of course, for testing purposes, you can cancel the navigation (as I have done in the code below) so that you don't actually navigate away and will be able to see the message.

By the way, a shortcut for typing `jquery` is `$`.

```js
// When all the HTML elements have been parsed into memory...
$(function() {
    // Get all the <a> elements that have a title attribute into a JQuery collection
    var $links = $("a[title]");
    
    // Give each member of the collection a click event handler
    $links.on("click", function(event){
       // Since clicking a link will navigate you away from this page,
       // we can stop that navigation (for testing purposes only) by
       // telling the event that is passed automatically to the function
       // to not continue
       event.preventDefault();
       
       // Then, we can access the specific element that triggered the event
       // via the "this" keyword and get its attribute value:
       console.log("you have selected " + $(this).attr('title'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title = "google" href="https://www.google.com">Visit google</a>
<a title = "Yahoo" href="https://www.yahoo.com">Visit This link</a>
<a title = "Verizon Wireless" href="https://www.Verizon.com">Visit Verizon</a>
<a title = "Social Media" href="https://www.facebook.com">Visit facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

***According to the question's title:*** (getting the value of an attribute **using javascript** every time a user clicks on a link)

## Your approach has some issues, let's analyze them

```
jquery(function() {
    var title = jquery(title).attr('title');    
    console.log("you have selected" + "" title);
});
```

Is missing the `+` operator to concatenate two strings.

```
console.log("you have selected" + "" title);
                                    ^
```

You're using the wrong `jquery` function, use `jQuery` instead (Javascript is case-sensitive).

```
jquery(function() {
^   var title = jquery(title).attr('title');    
                ^
    console.log("you have selected" + "" title);
});
```

Wrong tag enclosing for the last `a` element.

```
<a title = "Social Media" href="https://www.facebook.com">Visit facebook/a>
                                                                        ^
```

## Look at this code snippet (Javascript only)

*This approach is for situations where additional third-party frameworks like `jQuery` are not allowed*

```js
// This is the IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) to bind the clik event to your links

function bindClickEvent() {
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(a) {
    a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // This is to disable the default behavior of your links.

      var title = a.getAttribute('title');
      console.log("you have selected: " + title);
    });
  });
}

// Add this at the end of your body tag.
(function() {
  bindClickEvent();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="google 1" href="https://www.google.com">Visit google</a>
<a title="Yahoo" href="https://www.yahoo.com">Visit This link</a>
<a title="Verizon Wireless" href="https://www.Verizon.com">Visit Verizon</a>
<a title="Social Media" href="https://www.facebook.com">Visit facebook</a>
```

See? now your links were bound with click events.

## Resources

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)
- [Grammar and types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)

  > JavaScript is case-sensitive and uses the Unicode character set.